# how to open layer all layer at a fix position on the screen

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

[1st image-what i get 2nd image-what i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crDyE.png)I tried to set all layers at a point, when I tried to zoom the layer it changes the position of layer. I tried many times but i am unable to set the layer in center. please help me to solve this  problem. I want to fix the layer in center of screen. I used pure javascript language in my code and open layer lib.

```js
<script>
  var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(68.5094575, 6.6791812, 97.0315678, 35.3123975);
  var options = {
    controls: [],
    maxExtent: bounds,
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    maxResolution: 0.02741796875,
    center: [78.008072, 27.176670],
    units: 'm',
    zoom: 10
  };

  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map-id', options)
  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
    position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)
  }));

  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale());
  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
  map.addControl(new OpenLayer.Control.TransformFeature());
  map.getView().setCenter(78.008072, 27.176670);
  map.getView().setZoom(zoom);
</script>
<script>
  var popup;
  var currentLayer = null;
  var selectedVillageId = -1;

  function changeMap() {
    selectedVillageId = $('#village-filter').children("option:selected").val();
    var c = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(selectedVillageId, "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms", {
      srs: 'EPSG:32644',
      layers: 'ada_sazra:' + selectedVillageId,
      styles: '',
      format: 'image/png',
      tiled: 'true',
      tilesOrigin: map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
    }, {
      singleTile: true,
      ratio: 1
    });

    if (currentLayer == null) {
      currentLayer = c;
      map.addLayer(currentLayer);
    } else {
      map.removeLayer(currentLayer)
      currentLayer = c;
      map.addLayer(currentLayer);
    }
    map.zoomTo(8)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you can try map.getView().fit function to set a certain extent instead of just zooming map to a certain level.

Comment: i used this function  " map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize())" but it is not working.Please suggest any other solution.Thankyou.

Comment: can you show two screenshots: 1 . what you get 2. what you wish to get

Comment: I added image what i want to get,this time when i open application the layer moves to the left side and it hides. please solve this problem.

Comment: By the way are you sure your layer has a correct extent in its settings on a geoserver?

Comment: i am sure but can you please tell me that how to check correct extent in its setting because for making it correct i tried many times but failed.

Comment: for this i tried to open this layer on base map (open street map) but when try to open layer on base map then layer does not show.how to open layer on base map.

Comment: if you can see the whole layer by default when you view it in a geoserver (click OpenLayers in a layer row) then its extent is correct.

Comment: yes i can see the whole layer by default when i view it in a geoserver.

Comment: You can try to get a bonding box of a layer from a geoserver and pass a resulting extent to getView().fit function

Comment: i used this map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());

Comment: is a bounds variable layer's bounds?

Comment: yes,             var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(68.5094575, 6.6791812, 97.0315678, 35.3123975);

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/uttam1007/geoserver_web/src/uttam-web/src/

Comment: this is the link of layer file ,please check this and help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It seems you use OpenLayers 2.x. Can you use a newer version? Maybe this is a bug of 2.x. Can you create a small example with OpenLayers 4/5 and use the same layer?

Comment: sir please help me

Comment: how to use selectFeature in project  plz help me with code

Comment: selectFeature? Is it a new question not related to the current one above?

Comment: yes sir.. this is new question

Comment: layer position not set ....

Comment: please create a new question with a code showing selectFeature call